# What is proper event to update action bar?

Tags: android

My activity just includes a fragment container, and I'll shift different fragments in it. I want the action bar to show different action icons according to current fragment. For example, when fragment 1 is active, I want the action bar to show a navigation drop list, when fragment 2 is active, I want the action bar to show nothing.

My questions are:

1) What's a proper event to update action bar upon fragment replacement?

2) When fragment 2 becomes to active, how to restore the action bar to initial state (remove navigation drop list and maybe something else)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Store the reference to the menu in your activity. Create a private property in your activity:

```
private Menu mMenu;
```

2) Get the reference to the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_choice, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

3) You can then switch change the items in the action bar whenever you need to, e.g. I created that method to change the icon and title of an action bar item:

```
private void displayActionBar() {
    if (mMenu == null) return;

    if (mQuestionStage) {
        MenuItem nextItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_testNext);
        nextItem.setIcon(R.drawable.navigation_accept);
        nextItem.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_testCheck));
    } else
    {
        MenuItem nextItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_testNext);
        nextItem.setIcon(R.drawable.navigation_forward);
        nextItem.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_testNext));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the additional comments, here's how you can switch the drop down in the action bar (between showing and not showing it). You can use that code where you need it:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    else
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

Comment: Maybe this is not what I want. I don't want to use Menu. I need a drop-down list on action bar for fragment 1, and I need to remove the drop-down list from action bar before fragment 2 is replaced in.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to handle the ActionBar along with the Fragment's lifecycle rather than change it without a fragment switch (which might lead to user's confusion).

1. In you fragment's `onCreate()` method, notify the activity that you want to change the action bar by `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. Without this statement, your fragments `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will not be called even if you override it.
2. Change the actionbar by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and handle the response in `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, **all in fragments**. (BTW, if you are not handling a item click, remember to call `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` )
3. Remember to override the `onBackStackChanged()` method or use other ways to correctly handle the UI(e.g., actionbar) when back key is pressed and back stack is used. See [this android's develop guide article](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments) for details.

ps. if you simple want to remove prior fragment's actionbar item in a particular fragment, simply called `menu.clear()` in its `onCreateOptionsMenu()`